# rgb2gray not working, creating rainbow image

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-image

I'm trying to do data analysis on a series of photos, and when all photos are "changed" to grayscale from RGB, they are coming up as, well look:

[The standard Astronaut image as my system says it's grayscale](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vjpH.png)

Here's the code I'm using:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage.color import rgb2gray
from skimage import data
img = data.astronaut()
img_gray = rgb2gray(img)

plt.imshow(img_gray)
plt.show()
```

I also tried converting as hsv to rgb then grayscale, but it still produces a similar, non-grayscale image.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `matplotlib` shows the image 2D with its default colormap. Change your code to

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage.color import rgb2gray
from skimage import data
img = data.astronaut()
img_gray = rgb2gray(img)

plt.imshow(img_gray, cmap='gray')
plt.show()
```

You can also use

```
from skimage import io
io.imshow(img_gray)
```

which will handle grayscale images automatically